# ArrayMin on query column with a null value

Tags: coldfusion

CF8

I was using this line to get the MIN value of a query column.  I just noticed a null value in a recordset causes an error.   Is there a simply way to tell ArrayMin to skip nulls w/o having to loop the column and load an array with all non-null values?

```
<cfset temp_data_min = #round(ArrayMin(query_x["some_field"]))#>
```

thanks!

Comment: By the way: your `#` marks are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Just to check: is there a reason you can't exclude nulls from the original query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through your array and create a new array that doesn't contain any null values.  Then apply the ArrayMin function to the new array.

```
<cfset newArray = []>
<cfloop index="x" array="#query_x["some_field"]#">
  <cfif x NEQ 'null'>
      <cfset arrayAppend(newArray, x)>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfset temp_data_min = round(ArrayMin(newArray))>
```

NOT TESTED

Answer (score 5):

Building off of what Al said with using the query-of-queries, just adding the Min() call into the query.

```
<cfquery name="query_x_fixed" dbtype="query">
SELECT Min(some_field) as some_field
FROM query_x
WHERE some_field IS NOT NULL
</cfquery>

<cfset temp_data_min = round(query_x_fixed.some_field)>
```

Tested to work in CF9

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is probably to do a query-of-queries with just that column and remove the nulls.

```
<cfquery name="query_x_fixed" dbtype="query">
SELECT some_field
FROM query_x
WHERE some_field IS NOT NULL
</cfquery>

<cfset temp_data_min= round(ArrayMin(query_x_fixed["some_field"]))>
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the solution at one line by converting the column to a list then into an array.  `ListToArray` defaults to ignoring empty list items, which is what the null values will be.

```
<cfset temp_data_min = Round(ArrayMin(ListToArray(ValueList(query_x.some_field, Chr(7)), Chr(7))))>
```

This should be faster than any of the other proposed solutions and is less code.

I've specified the delimiter for locales that use the comma as the decimal separator in numbers.  If you're in the US or another locale that uses the "." then you can remove the delimiter arguments.

Additional functions used:

- [ListToArray](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_21.html)
- [ValueList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_13.html)
- [Chr](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_04.html)